# Custom table view cell not working.

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm attempting to setup custom table cells and I have completed the steps without any errors but the table does not show any data still.

This is my Table View Controller

```
import UIKit

class CharacterTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet var characterTableView: UITableView!

var characterArray: [Character] = [Character]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.characterArray.count;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:CharacterTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CharacterTableViewCell


    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    let character = characterArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = character.name
    cell.abilityLabel.text = character.abilities
    cell.characterImage.image = UIImage(named: character.characterImage)


    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
}
```

And this is the custom cell class

```
import UIKit

class CharacterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var abilityLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var characterImage: UIImageView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

Sorry for the long post. Everything is properly linked. Can someone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Check if your tableview's `delegate` and `dataSource` properties in interface builder are connected to your view controller.

Comment: BTW: `UITableViewController` already implements `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols hence there is no need to type them again.

Comment: If you made the cell in a storyboard or xib, you shouldn't register the class. If you made the cell entirely in code, then you should register your custom class, not UITableViewCell

Comment: Is you cell defined in separate Xib? Or cell defined in StoryBoard within table? I've noticed that cell's reuse identifier that you register is typed with lower case `cell` while you dequeue `Cell` (first letter is upper case)

Comment: @rdelmar I commented out the register line but nothing changed.

Comment: @Keenle I tried running it with the correctly cased identifier but no difference. And yes they are connected in the interface builder to the datasource and the delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should have one `reuseIdentifier` when calling `registerClass` and when calling `dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier`
2. you should register your class name, not `UITableViewCell` instance.

e.g.:

```
class CharacterTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
[...]
let reuseIdentifier = "CellIdentifier"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.registerClass(CharacterTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}
[...]
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:CharacterTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier) as CharacterTableViewCell
[...]
```